# How would i change a CSS class for each item i'm retrieving from a DB?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

How would i change the bootstrap CSS grid class for each item i'm retrieving from a DB?
    'while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {' 
so they are nested in a 3x3 grid.

```
<div class="container">  
  <div class="row">  
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="panel-body"><?php echo '<img class = "resize" src="images/'.$product_image.'" />'; ?></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this I hope this will work.

```
<div class="container">  
  <div class="row">
    <?php
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel-body"><?php echo '<img class = "resize" src="images/'.$product_image.'" />'; ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php 
      } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```